# How to position a css radial gradient to the top left responsively?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div class="wrapper">` with a background image.

Inside of that I have a `<div class="inner">` which is 100% height and width.

I want to giver `.inner` a *radial* background which originates from the top left corner.

I can position it with `background-position: value;` but the width of `.wrapper` will vary depending on screen size.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="inner">
      <h3>title</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  background-image:url('www.example.com/example.png')
}

.inner {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want to accomplish:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/11/22/05/background-1134468_960_720.jpg) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="inner">
      <h3> title </h3>
   </div>
</div>
```